# Parsing a float to an array of uchar C++

Tags: c++, arrays, binary

To fit the need of a specific programming library, I must take a float value and store it in an array comprising of unsigned chars (0-255 range) in C++.

Say that I have

```
float x = 32.453;
unsigned int xx = x * 1000; // xx == 32453, since I want to keep the 3 decimals
```

If I convert manually 32453 to a binary format: 0b 0111 1110 1100 0101 or 0x7EC5

So, I would like to have an array of unsigned chars:

```
unsigned char parsednumber [2];
parsednumber[0] = 0x7E;
parsednumber[1] = 0xC5;
```

So far I have:

```
float number = 32.453
unsigned int numberuint = number * 1000;

unsigned char parsednumber [2];
parsednumber[0] = (numberuint << 8) >> 8;
parsednumber[1] = numberuint >> 8;
cout << parsednumber << endl;
```

I try to use left shift and right shift to select the upper and lower part of numberint, but right now all I get in *parsednumber* is gibberish...

Comment: `xx` already holds what you want. simply `memcpy` it to your destination.

Comment: Does the library stipulate the format or size of the uchar array? Or are you dealing with a network transport that wants a *pointer to a uchar array* and a size?

Comment: The lib actually needs a 128, 256, 512, etc. bits value, that is split in an array of "n" uchars (bytes actually) as an input (you have two inputs). The function works that way so I have to comply. It is for low level operations on bit and use assembly and SSE2 or 3 under the hood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned char parsednumber [2];
parsednumber[0] = (numberuint << 8) >> 8;
parsednumber[1] = numberuint >> 8;
```

The assignment to parsednumber[0] is probably not what you need.  You're just
shifting it 8 bits to the left, then undoing it with an 8 bit right shift.
It might clear the upper bits, or it might not.

Instead, consider this (assuming least significant byte first):

```
unsigned char parsednumber [2];
parsednumber[0] = numberuint & 0xff;
parsednumber[1] = (numberuint >> 8) & 0xff;
```

Here we explicitly mask out the bits we're not interested in for each byte.

When you print the result, keep in mind that it's not a null-terminated
string, and it may contain non-printable characters.

Comment: Conceptually, I understand what you mean. But, for a numberuint value of 32453, I get the following values (in debug mode with a breakpoint in VS2013):

parsednumber[0] == 0x197
parsednumber[1] == 0x126

If I interpret this correctly, the resulting number would be 0x126197, which is 1204631... So it means I misinterpret the results... I simply want to validate that it works in my code!

Comment: I have not been looking at the right value, dumb me ^^ it works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: 197 decimal= C5 hex,  126 decimal = 7E hex, and 7EC5 hex = 32453 as expected.  (I was thrown at first by the 0x prefix...)  So it indeed seems to be working.